# WPF: pure XAML when lunch Storyboard base of binding condition

Tags: wpf, storyboard

So i have this `Storyboard`:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="animate">
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:2.0"/>
</Storyboard>
```

My binding `value`:

```
public bool IsFound
{
    get { return _isFound; }
    set
    {
        _isFound= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And my `Grid` that get this `Storyboard`:

```
<Grid name="myGrid">
   ....
<Grid>


if(IsFound)
{
    Storyboard storyboard = Resources["animate"] as Storyboard;
        if (storyboard != null)
            storyboard.Begin(myGrid);
}
```

So i am looking for something pure `XAML` instead of checking this `IsFound` in code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a DataTrigger:

```
<Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="MyAnimatedGrid">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFound}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard StoryBoard="{StaticResource animate}" />
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```